# Cómo incrustar un componente react dentro de otro componente react?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo react y estoy haciendo un form, y tengo los siguientes componentes:

```
const Form = ()=>{
    return (
        <form className = "Form"  id = "form"></form>
    )
}

const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <input type="text" className = "Input" id = "input" placeholder = {props.placeholder}></input>
    )
}
```

y lo que quisiera es incrustar Input dentro de Form, por ejemplo en html sería algo como:

```
<form>
    <input>
</form>
```

Quiero hacer eso pero en React con los componentes Form e Input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo capturando el `props.children` en el componente padre y luego renderizarlo en el mismo.

```js
const MyFormComponent = (props) =>{
    return (
        <form className = "Form"  id = "form">
            {props.children}
        </form>
    )
}

const MyInputComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <input type="text" className = "Input" id = "input" placeholder = {props.placeholder}></input>
    )
}
```

> Recuerda que los componentes de React deben empezar con letra
> mayuscula.

Al final para incrsutarlo debe quedar algo asi:

```
<MyFormComponent>
    <MyInputComponent />
</MyFormComponent>
```